# Probability Theory textbooks similar to Bressoud's books

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

I am reading Bressoud's book *A Radical Approach to Lebesgue's Theory of Integration* and I am finding it to be exactly how I feel that every introductory math textbook should be written: With tons of context to make all of the topics meaningful, natural, and motivated.

After I finish this text I intend to move on to studying Probability Theory and topics which are downstream of that.  Are there any texts for these sorts of topics, which give similar context, history, or motivations as a main part of the text?

Comment: I would say that the first volume of Feller's probability could be a book that will work for you.